# Resizable alsoresize in one direction only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

I am trying to use the jQuery UI Resizable feature. I would like to
only add a south/west resize handler on one object, so it will resize
to the west and south. When it resizes, I would like to simultaneously
resize another object, but only in the 'south' direction. I am trying
to use the alsoresize property, but it seems always resizes the second
object by the same amount in both directions. Does any one know how to
achieve this?

Thank you,

Eric

Answer (score 6):

Try this fellow Eric! There might be some issues with margin/padding.

```
$('.main').resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui)
    {
        $('.also').css("width",ui.size.width+"px");
    }
});
```